# What happened to the humans who sided with the Machines before the Machine War?

Tags: the-matrix

The Animatrix short *The Second Renaissance* chronicles the events from the creation of [synthetic intelligences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_intelligence) through to the defeat and enslavement of humanity. What I'm interested in is the period from B1-66ER's "trial" through the founding of 01 city. [According to the wiki](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Machines#History):

> Some humans were on the machine's side thinking they should have rights; these Liberals and civil Rights Activists were eventually purged by the Government. While other humans maintained that machines were nothing more than property, and after the Liberals were purged, the Conservative faction rose to become supreme amonst the World governments, and eventually mandated the destruction of all intelligent machines and the persecution of all pro-Machine supporters.

I find it difficult to believe that even a totalitarian, world-encompassing regime could imprison or kill *all* their human political enemies (never mind being able to justify doing such). Furthermore there were surely a number of humans who were able to conceal their sympathy for the Machines and survive long enough to make an attempt to escape from the xenophobic majority of humanity to 01 after its founding.

The answer is possibly that the Machines simply became as xenophobic as the majority of humans and as such, would have prevented any human presence in 01. But given that they are logical machines, I feel that they would be hesitant to destroy or reject humans who were willing to help them.

**Is any evidence (or inference) to prove or disprove that the Machines and humanity were totally divided and isolated from each other by the time of the Machine War?**

Comment: They would have been the first to die in the nuke attacks on 01

Comment: @Richard 01 survived those attacks, which implies that the machines had some sort of defence mechanism in place to prevent their total destruction. If there were any humans living in 01 at the time, I'd expect those same defences to have protected them.

Comment: The implication is that their defence was simply that nukes are largely ineffective against machines. Worthy of asking as a separate question, possibly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**We don't know.** The sequence in '[Second Renaissance, Part I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdQceIJ-t-M)' that deals with the pre-war tension between the newly sentient machines (and their sympathisers) and those who're opposed to their independence is largely covered in a single 3 minute snippet about the 'Million Machine March'

No further mention is made of human sympathisers elsewhere (in the other Animatrix shorts, Matrix comics, films, games or commentaries), nor are they mentioned in the films.

If there were any sympathisers living in 01, they were most likely killed in the [initial attack on the city](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpP9me2A2ao&feature=youtu.be&t=59s). Certainly the machines survived but any humans would have suffered terribly from the fallout and blast effects.

> **Narrator:** *The prolonged barrage engulfed Zero One in the glow of a thousand suns. But unlike their former masters with their delicate
>   flesh, the machines had little to fear of the bombs' radiation and
>   heat.*

---

We do know (courtesy of The Matrix Online game) that a small group of human leaders who collaborated with the Machines prior to the Machine War were able to hide themselves in a compound. These [Oligarchs](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Oligarchy) don't appear to be linked to the humans in the description in the Second Renaissance though, as they were unknown to the Zionese when that was written.